# What is the best way to get parameters from a route in zf2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

There are multiple ways to get parameters from a route in zf2.  A couple include

```
$pageID = (int)$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('pageID');
```

and

```
$pageID = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('pageID', 0);
```

Which is the best, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pageID = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('pageID', 0);
```

This is the controller action helper call and should be used inside your controller.
Inside the helper

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam()
```

is called.

As u can see - both ways are legit - the helper call is, as the name says, a tool to spare you some typing.

You can use the first way to get parameters inside an attached event for example, most of the time used when u attach something to the default ZF2 events like dispatch, render ...

greetings